# findAll on non object in extbase

Tags: repository, extbase, findall, typo3-4.5

I just created an extension in typo3 4.5 with one model (product). I created the "productRepository" then injected it in the ProductController but I still get the

```
Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object
```

here is how the ProductController looks like :

```
/**
 * @var Tx_PiProductDetail_Domain_Repository_ProductRepository
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * @param Tx_PiProductDetail_Domain_Repository_ProductRepository $productRepository
 * @return void
 */
public function injectProductRepository(Tx_PiProductDetail_Domain_Repository_ProductRepository $productRepository) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {
    $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('products', $products);
}
```

and the ProductRepository :

```
class Tx_PiProductDetail_Domain_Repository_ProductRepository extends Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Repository { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with the `object` and `reflection caching` in Extbase.

In `TYPO3 4.5` you should `truncate` manually all `cache` related tables in your database. I guess the related tables for the Extbase object and reflection caching are `cf_extbase_object`, `cf_extbase_object_tags`, `bcf_extbase_reflection` and `cf_extbase_reflection_tags` but I'm not sure.

In `TYPO3 4.5` you can avoid the problem while developing by adding this to your `typo3conf/localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['extbase_reflection']['backend'] = 't3lib_cache_backend_NullBackend';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['extbase_object']['backend'] = 't3lib_cache_backend_NullBackend';
```

Comment: thank you ! but do you think just by adding those 2 lines in localconf.php file the job would get done ? I mean I don't see where the new table is specified !

Comment: They are not new tables, just a reference to a class which resolves your caching problem while developing your extension. So if you add those 2 lines to your conf file you should `clear all caches` and maybe remove all content from `typo3temp` to fix it.

Comment: ok .. I know there are not new tables .. but where should I then tell the model which table it should use.

Comment: Extbase calculates the target table based on your model/repository name. The only thing what we just do with those lines is telling extbase to do not cache your objects. See also: http://blog.alexanderschnitzler.de/disable-extbase-reflection-cache-during-development.html

Comment: Php tells you `Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object`, so since your repository extends `Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Repository` which has the `findAll()` method the only thing what can be going on here is that `injectProductRepository()` did not inject your repository (object) well. So if you var_dump() your repository inside your action than you probably see NULL which means that the repository is not injected by `injectProductRepository()`, To avoid that while developing you use those 2 lines.

Comment: So basically all `injections` are being cached, and there is no check if there are new injections. So or you should clear the caches manually which triggers Extbase to take into account the new injections, or you can avoid the caching by using those 2 lines.

Comment: ahh now I understand why I was feeling lost ... I already fixed that issue and put another question related to how to configure a Model to use an existing table ==> [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460641/configure-model-to-use-an-existing-table-in-extbase)

Comment: hehehe okok just accept my answer then lol. I will answer your other question as well for you :)