# Configure model to use an existing table in extbase

Tags: model, extbase

I built an extension in Typo3 4.5 using extbase. automatically was new table for a product model created with the name "tx_piproductdetail_domain_model_product",but my hope is to set it to use the already existing table "tx_piproducts_domain_model_product" instead.  I tried to modify the TCA file .. but couldn't make it . Here is how the TCA file is configured for that model

http://laravel.io/bin/W44z5.

Answer (score 0):

> http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#typoscript-configuration
>
> **persistence.classes**
>
> This settings are used with individual classes. That includes in particular the mapping of classes and property names to tables and field names.

Mapping of existing tables to your model can be done with a TypoScript setup, here's an example how your setup should look like:

**Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt**

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Tx_PiProductDetail_Domain_Model_Product {
    mapping {
        tableName = tx_piproducts_domain_model_product
        columns {
            some_column_name.mapOnProperty = someColumnName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well , I tried and it did not work .. this is how I defined it in my setup.txt           http://laravel.io/bin/roo0Q  . Would you please check if I did it the right way. otherwise, how could I make sure this modification has taken place ?