# My TYPO3 CMS 6.2 Extbase extension crashes while passing objects between multiple controllers and action methods and persistence

Tags: controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I'm writing a TYPO3 extension using TYPO3 CMS 6.2.x LTS and Extension Builder. The extension should be importing a CSV file into a domain model and populating two more models during import.

The CSV file imports okay, but a following controller method is crashing, and I'm having trouble solving the problem. I believe that the problem source may be hidden in the fact that my plugin calls the first method, but then each method goes directly to the next method. Extbase documentation leads me to believe `forward()` will not return to the calling method, and I need to return to the original method to continue processing more import records.

My plugin URI activates `ImportMemberController->importAction()`. `ImportMemberController->importAction()` passes a `$newPerson` object and a `$parameters` array to `PersonController->enrollAction()` okay. `PersonController->enrollAction()` passes `$person`, `$role`, `$startTime`, and `$stopTime` objects to `HasRoleController->commissionAction()` okay. `HasRoleController->commissionAction()` crashes on the final `persistAll()` line with the following message.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function persistAll() on null in
>   typo3conf\ext\myextension\Classes\Controller\HasRoleController.php on
>   line 157

Configurations including TCA are generally intact from when they were built by Extension Builder.

Here is some of the extension's code. My apologies for the length.

```
<?php
namespace MyNameSpace\Myextension\Controller;
/**
 * ImportMemberController
 */
class ImportMemberController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * importMemberRepository
     * 
     * @var \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Repository\ImportMemberRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $importMemberRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * personRepository
     *
     * @var \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Repository\PersonRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $personRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
     * @inject
     */
    protected $persistenceManager;

    /**
     * action import
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function importAction() {
        $importMembers = $this->importMemberRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($importMembers as $importMember) {

            // Assess the qualification of this import person.
            $newQualification = TRUE;
            if ($importMember->getEmail() == "") {
                $newQualification = FALSE;
            }
            elseif ($importMember->getFirstName() == "") {
                $newQualification = FALSE;
            }
            elseif ($importMember->getLastName() == "") {
                $newQualification = FALSE;
            }

            // Determine whether this person is already in the personRepository.
            $queryResult = $this->personRepository->findBySomeNumber($importMember->getSomeNumber());
            if ($queryResult->count() > 0) {
                $person = $queryResult->getFirst();
                // Update changes to an existing person's specified properties.
                if ($person->getFamilyName() != $importMember->getLastName()) {
                    $person->setFamilyName($importMember->getLastName());
                }
                if ($person->getFirstName() != $importMember->getFirstName()) {
                    $person->setFirstName($importMember->getFirstName());
                }
                if ($person->getEmailAddress() != $importMember->getEmail()) {
                    $person->setEmailAddress($importMember->getEmail());
                }
                $this->personRepository->update($person);
                // Obtain the qualification status of this existing person.
                $existingQualification = $person->getQualifiedUser();
                // Disenroll this existing person if they no longer qualify.
                if ($existingQualification && !$newQualification) {
                    $person->setQualifiedUser(FALSE);
                }
                // Else enroll this existing person if they qualify after being unqualified.
                elseif (!$existingQualification && $newQualification) {
                    $person->setQualifiedUser(TRUE); // @todo: Reevaluate the need for this instruction.
                }
                // Else act if this existing person qualifies but changed  Office.
                elseif ($existingQualification && $newQualification && 2==1) {
                    // @todo: Later.
                }
            }
            else {
                // Act if this new import person qualifies.
                if ($newQualification) {
                    // Enter this new import person into personRepository.
                    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
                    $newPerson = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Model\\Person');
                    $newPerson->setFamilyName($importMember->getLastName());
                    $newPerson->setFirstName($importMember->getFirstName());
                    $newPerson->setSomeNumber($importMember->getSomeNumber());
                    $newPerson->setEmailAddress($importMember->getEmail());
                    $this->personRepository->add($newPerson);
                    $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
                    // Enroll this new import person.
                    if ($importMember->getDate()) {
                        $startTime = $importMember->getDate();
                    }
                    else {
                        $startTime = new \DateTime();
                    }
                    if ($importMember->getPaidThru()) {
                        $stopTime = $importMember->getPaidThru();
                    }
                    else {
                        $stopTime = new \DateTime();
                        $stopTime->modify('+100 years');
                    }
                    $parameters = array(
                        'title' => ' Office '.$importMember->getOffice().' Member',
                        'startTime' => $startTime,
                        'stopTime' => $stopTime
                    );
                    $newPersonController = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Controller\\PersonController');
                    $newPersonController->enrollAction($newPerson, $parameters);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect('list');
    }
}

<?php
namespace MyNameSpace\Myextension\Controller;
/**
 * PersonController
 */
class PersonController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * personRepository
     * 
     * @var \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Repository\PersonRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $personRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * roleRepository
     *
     * @var \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Repository\RoleRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $roleRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * action enroll
     *
     * @param \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person
     * @param mixed[] $parameters
     * @return void
     */
    public function enrollAction(\MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person,
                                $parameters) {
        $person->setQualifiedUser(TRUE);
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $this->roleRepository = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Repository\\RoleRepository');
        if ($parameters['title']) {
            $queryResult = $this->roleRepository->findByTitle($parameters['title']);
            if ($queryResult->count() > 0) {
                $role = $queryResult->getFirst();
                if ($parameters['startTime']) {
                    $startTime = $parameters['startTime'];
                } else {
                    $startTime = new \DateTime();
                }
                if ($parameters['stopTime']) {
                    $stopTime = $parameters['stopTime'];
                } else {
                    $stopTime = new \DateTime();
                    $stopTime->modify('+100 years');
                }
                $newHasRoleController = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Controller\\HasRoleController');
                $newHasRoleController->commissionAction($person, $role, $startTime, $stopTime);
            }
        }
    }
}

<?php
namespace MyNameSpace\Myextension\Controller;
/**
 * HasRoleController
 */
class HasRoleController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * hasRoleRepository
     * 
     * @var \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Repository\HasRoleRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $hasRoleRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager
     * @inject
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * persistence manager
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\PersistenceManagerInterface
     * @inject
     */
    protected $persistenceManager;

    /**
     * action commission
     *
     * @param \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person
     * @param \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Role $role
     * @param \DateTime $startTime
     * @param \DateTime $stopTime
     * @return void
     */
    public function commissionAction(\MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person,
                                    \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Role $role,
                                    $startTime, $stopTime) {
        //$newHasRole = new \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\HasRole(); // @todo: Remove this line.
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Arguments::class);
        $newHasRole = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Model\\HasRole');
        //$newHasRole = $this->objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Model\\HasRole');
        $newHasRole->setStartTime($startTime);
        $newHasRole->setStopTime($stopTime);
        $newHasRole->addPerson($person);
        //$newHasRole->setPerson($person); // @todo: Remove this line.
        $newHasRole->addRole($role);
        //$newHasRole->setRole($person); // @todo: Remove this line.
        $this->hasRoleRepository = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Repository\\HasRoleRepository');
        //$this->hasRoleRepository = $this->objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Repository\\HasRoleRepository');
        $this->hasRoleRepository->add($newHasRole);
        $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
    }
}
```

At the crash point, the variables in local scope are:

```
$newHasRole = object(MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\HasRole)
  protected 'startTime' => 
    object(DateTime)[834]
      public 'date' => string '1993-11-29 19:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
  protected 'stopTime' => 
    object(DateTime)[982]
      public 'date' => string '2116-03-10 17:55:43.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
  protected 'person' => 
    object(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage)[1008]
      private 'warning' => string 'You should never see this warning. If you do, you probably used PHP array functions like current() on the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage. To retrieve the first result, you can use the rewind() and current() methods.' (length=228)
      protected 'storage' => 
        array (size=1)
          '000000007303096700000000080231e7' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      protected 'isModified' => boolean true
      protected 'addedObjectsPositions' => 
        array (size=1)
          '000000007303096700000000080231e7' => int 1
      protected 'removedObjectsPositions' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'positionCounter' => int 1
  protected 'role' => 
    object(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage)[1045]
      private 'warning' => string 'You should never see this warning. If you do, you probably used PHP array functions like current() on the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage. To retrieve the first result, you can use the rewind() and current() methods.' (length=228)
      protected 'storage' => 
        array (size=1)
          '0000000073030eea00000000080231e7' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      protected 'isModified' => boolean true
      protected 'addedObjectsPositions' => 
        array (size=1)
          '0000000073030eea00000000080231e7' => int 1
      protected 'removedObjectsPositions' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'positionCounter' => int 1
  protected 'uid' => null
  protected '_localizedUid' => null
  protected '_languageUid' => null
  protected '_versionedUid' => null
  protected 'pid' => null
  private '_isClone' (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject) => boolean false
  private '_cleanProperties' (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

$objectManager = object(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager)
$person = object(KeystoneResearchSolutions\Grouprole\Domain\Model\Person)
$role = object(KeystoneResearchSolutions\Grouprole\Domain\Model\Role)
$startTime = object(DateTime)
$stopTime = object(DateTime)
```

Comment: You injected persistence manager but didn't clear all caches.... you must clear really ALL to reflect new injects. Even purge the typo3temp folder in some  cases

Comment: Thank you! I go into the TYPO3 Install Tool's "important actions" and clear all caches, then "clean up" all matching temporary files, before each debug run. Am I missing a prep step? Is there a "clear all" instruction within Extbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly getting a Persistence Manager from the Object Manager solved the problem. This is despite the Persistence Manager injection already present at the head of the class.

The clue to the solution came from [Arek van Schaijk's 2015-05-26 14:18 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455040/findall-on-non-object-in-extbase/30460829#comment-49002823) at [findAll on non object in extbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455040/findall-on-non-object-in-extbase/30460829) saying "the only thing what can be going on here is that `injectProductRepository()` did not inject your repository (object) well." And the next comment says, "So basically all injections are being cached, and there is no check if there are new injections." Apparently in some situations the Extbase injection mechanism doesn't engage.

Here is the function code that worked:

```
/**
 * action commission
 *
 * @param \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person
 * @param \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Role $role
 * @param \DateTime $startTime
 * @param \DateTime $stopTime
 * @return void
 */
public function commissionAction(\MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Person $person,
                                 \MyNameSpace\Myextension\Domain\Model\Role $role,
                                 $startTime, $stopTime) {
    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
    $newHasRole = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Model\\HasRole');
    $newHasRole->setStartTime($startTime);
    $newHasRole->setStopTime($stopTime);
    $newHasRole->addPerson($person);
    $newHasRole->addRole($role);
    $this->hasRoleRepository = $objectManager->get('MyNameSpace\\Myextension\\Domain\\Repository\\HasRoleRepository');
    $this->hasRoleRepository->add($newHasRole);
    $this->persistenceManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager');
    $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should really be no need to manually persist the object as extbase automatically persists changes to objects if associated with a repository at the end of each action.

Comment: I agree with you in theory. Manually persisting adds overhead, and I'll have 20,000+ records to import and process on a routine basis. However, earlier code versions were not tracking and storing UIDs for the newly created Person and HasRole objects. Do you have an alternative that can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need the uids for further logic within the same action call?

Comment: Hmm. importAction() will call enrollAction() once per person, but enrollAction() can call commissionAction() several times per person; then the cycle repeats for the next person. An earlier code version successfully saved HasRole objects into the database, but their Person UIDs were "1" in all records instead of matching each Person's actual UID.

Answer (score 0):

You injected persistence manager but didn't clear all caches.... you must clear really ALL to reflect new injects. Even purge the typo3temp folder in some cases.

To add the `Flush system caches` icon for selected users in BE without need of using Install Tool just edit required account and add this to its `TSConfig`:

```
options.clearCache.system = 1
```

Save the user and refresh whole BE by pressing F5.

It's rather bad idea to allow anyone to clear system caches (especially on large instances) so keep this possibility only for devs and clever admins.

Comment: Flushing system caches didn't work. Program crashes at the same persistAll() instruction with the same results on local variables in scope.

Comment: Well you need to debug yourself why your persistence manager is null I don't even know which line in your sample is 157 ;) `Call to a member function persistAll() on null ... on line 157`

Comment: Line 157 is the `$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();` line at the end of the sample. Thanks for your comments, and I'll keep debugging.

Comment: first step to debugging is `if(is_null($this->persistenceManager)) die('persistence manager is null!);`